# Robert Heinlein character quote about Hell and kittens

Tags: robert-a-heinlein, quotes

I keep vaguely remembering a character in one of Robert Heinlein's books saying something along the lines "there was a special place in hell for child molesters and people who drown kittens."

I just wonder what the actual quote was because it mentions cats and it keeps bubbling up in my memory.

Comment: Searching online for this quote is not for the faint of heart.

Comment: sounds like something my idol, Baslim the Cripple would say

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Possibly this, taken from [*Friday*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/17208.Friday) (1982), nothing about child molesters though:

> "I can't. Mama cat and her kittens. Black Beauty and Demon and Star and Red... I *can't*".
>
> There wasn't anything to say, so I didn't. **The coldest depth of Hell is reserved for people who abandon kittens.**

---

Found... Probably by overkilling it. I searched this site for `Heinlein quote cat`, found [Did Robert Heinlein write about his real-life cats?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/183558/), googled `grumbles from the grave heinlein quote kitten` and found the quote. Obviously `Heinlein quote kitten` worked just as fine in the end...

Comment: I miss Kitten Smith... too bad about Klendathu.

Comment: Thank You! I knew this was probably the quote last night, but I like to let answers ride a little while to see if I get confirmation or alternatives. I've read ALL of Heinlein books multiple times and I guess enough years have passed that it's time to start over. It's a wonder that I haven't named any of the cats we've gotten Pilxle.
Tanstafl

Comment: "Pixel" and not whatever I wrote.

Answer (score 7):

There was also a similar line in *The Cat Who Walks Through Walls*. One of the characters in the last chapter meditates on how killing a kitten is the worst thing a person can do.

> "Who was writing our story? Was he going to let us live?
>
> Anyone who would kill a baby kitten is cruel, mean cruel.
>   I hate you. I despise you!"

Comment: This is the one that immediately came to my mind.  The character is actually berating the author of their own story; Heinlein himself.